# What needs to be done to respect the volume/ringing settings with voip app on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip

Have a twilio app that allows users to receive calls while backgrounded.  The app currently plays the ringing that is provided by Twilio.

I am looking to respect the volume settings of the user's device, if it's in silent mode then vibrate, if it's in Do Not Disturb don't do anything.  Currently it rings regardless of mode.

I've not been able to find documentation indicating if this is possible or how it could be done while the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` as: Sounds play at the current system audio volume, with no programmatic volume control available